# Regex match mutiple string following sequence

Tags: regex

e.g :

```
#&)$&)#$# insert into ... DB3_table1
$&&@# insert into ... DB2_TABLE1
#&@)$@# select into ... DB1_TABLE1
#)#@&)$ select into ... DB1_TABLE2
#$$# insert into ... DB2_TABLE2
#&)$&)#$# select into ... DB3_TABLE2
```

input :
`insert` and `TABLE1`

expected output :

```
#&)$&)#$# insert into ... DB3_table1
$&&@# insert into ... DB2_TABLE1
```

what i've tried :
`insert*TABLE1` and it's not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can input `insert.*table1` to do it.

the logic :

> .* = .{0,} = match any char zero or more times

[image]